# Space child components along full height of a fixed-height parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app with a page that displays an overlay over a map. I want the view on this overlay to be scaled to a percentage of screen height (30%). I want the contents of this view to be flex elements that span its entire height.

This is my current implementation:

```
  function MyOverlay () {
  return (
      <Overlay isVisible={true}>
        <View id='container' style={{height: '30%', alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
          <Text id='title' style={{flex: 1}, styles.titleText}>Menu</Text>
          <View id='options' style={{flex: 3}}>
            <Button containerStyle={{borderWidth: 2, flex: 1}}>
              Option 1
            </Button>
            <Button containerStyle={{borderWidth: 2, flex: 1}}>
              Option 2
            </Button>
            <Button containerStyle={{borderWidth: 2, flex: 1}}>
              Option 3
            </Button>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Overlay>
  );
};
```

In this implementation, `container` has height=30%, which is reflected in the screenshot below. I want the `title` and `options` child components to fill the entire parent height. After reading other answers, I added `alignItems: 'stretch'` to `container`. This isn't working as intended, as seen in the screenshot.

[image: App View]

Any idea how I could get the behavior that I want?

Comment: The options should be tall?  as in 1/3 total height, or spaced evenly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your example in my own markup, and abstracted away the styles for readability.  Most of the styles you can ignore, but the important stuff is:

On the parent container:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

On the option wrapper:

```
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
```

And that's it!  No need to add any flex properties to the children.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
    
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button>Option 1</button>
    <button>Option 2</button>
    <button>Option 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```